# How to connect/use BPRV2125AM?

Tags: photodiode

We want to know how exactly do we make the connections of the photodetector since they are so fragile.Can we do a PCB,  and if so is there any IC base for it.How do we work the RF output as we need to connect it to the BNC connector.
https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/UTAG/UTAGS00060/UTAGS00060-1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

They have an evaluation kit according to the datasheet you linked.

> The u2t Evaluation Kit EVA-BPRV serves as easy-to-use utility to characterize a single u2t photoreceiver BPRV2125A under laboratory conditions. The kit consists of a PCB (printed circuit board), a DC cable set 
>   and 4 socket head screws 4-40 UNC (see picture).

Otherwise yes you will need a printed circuit board. The RF output is on pins 17 and 18. You should ask them what the output impedance is of that differential output so you can properly match it. Its probably 100-ohm differential / 50-ohm single ended, but truly it shouldn't be guessed.

Comment: Thank You so much for your feedback! I am looking into the evaluation kit but i cannot seem to find it and maybe it they do not sell it. Not quite sure.I think we connect one of the output to a 50 ohm resistor but the other end is what i am more concerned about.

Comment: look around manufacturer's website. Often the designs of evaluation boards are freely available and you might be able to reproduce it for yourself.